# Spring in Action book chapter 4 author's code not working (autowire error message)

Tags: spring

I know Java, but I'm new to IntelliJ and Spring. I'm using code provided by the book "Spring in Action," so I know it's supposed to work. In Chapter 4 (Security), the program's SecurityConfig.java file contains these lines:

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

The userDetailsService variable is highlighted with this compilation error:

```
Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'UserDetailsService' type.Beans:inMemoryUserDetailsManager (UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class)userRepositoryUserDetailsService&nbsp;&nbsp; (UserRepositoryUserDetailsService.java)
```

Can you provide guidance?

Although I’ve read about it, I don’t fully understand autowiring. I wish I could attach files, but apparently I can't do that. As a poor alternative, I'll paste the code for the Securityconfig.java file at the bottom of this post (sorry for the length).

Can you suggest what I might need to do to resolve the problem?

Securityconfig.java file:

```java
//tag::securityConfigOuterClass[]
package tacos.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
//end::securityConfigOuterClass[]
//tag::baseBonesImports[]
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web
                        .configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web
                        .configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
//end::baseBonesImports[]

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation
             .authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web
             .builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder;

//tag::securityConfigOuterClass[]

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  
//end::securityConfigOuterClass[]

//tag::customUserDetailsService[]

// @@ The following userDetailService declaration generated this compilation error:
// "Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of UserDetailsService type"
// IntelliJ support told me:
// The error is caused by tacos.security.UserRepositoryUserDetailsService,
// which has the clause implements UserDetailsService.
// Remove that class.
// So I removed that class and the error disappeared.
  // But runtime error: "Error starting ApplicationContext."

  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
  
//end::customUserDetailsService[]

  //tag::configureHttpSecurity[]
  //tag::authorizeRequests[]
  //tag::customLoginPage[]
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/design", "/orders")
          .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
        .antMatchers("/", "/**").access("permitAll")
        //end::authorizeRequests[]
        
      .and()
        .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/login")
        //end::customLoginPage[]
          
      // tag::enableLogout[]
      .and()
        .logout()
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
      // end::enableLogout[]
          
      // Make H2-Console non-secured; for debug purposes
      // tag::csrfIgnore[]
      .and()
        .csrf()
          .ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")
      // end::csrfIgnore[]

      // Allow pages to be loaded in frames from the same origin; needed for H2-Console
      // tag::frameOptionsSameOrigin[]
      .and()  
        .headers()
          .frameOptions()
            .sameOrigin()
      // end::frameOptionsSameOrigin[]
            
      //tag::authorizeRequests[]
      //tag::customLoginPage[]
      ;
  }
//end::configureHttpSecurity[]
//end::authorizeRequests[]
//end::customLoginPage[]

  /*
  //tag::customUserDetailsService[]
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {

    auth
      .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    
  }
  //end::customUserDetailsService[]
  
   */

  //tag::customUserDetailsService_withPasswordEncoder[]
  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new StandardPasswordEncoder("53cr3t");
  }
  
  
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {

    auth
      .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
      .passwordEncoder(encoder());
    
  }
  //end::customUserDetailsService_withPasswordEncoder[]
  
//
// IN MEMORY AUTHENTICATION EXAMPLE
//
/*
//tag::configureAuthentication_inMemory[]
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {
    
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("buzz")
          .password("infinity")
          .authorities("ROLE_USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("woody")
          .password("bullseye")
          .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    
  }
//end::configureAuthentication_inMemory[]
*/

//
// JDBC Authentication example
//
/*
//tag::configureAuthentication_jdbc[]
  @Autowired
  DataSource dataSource;
  
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {
    
    auth
      .jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource);
    
  }
//end::configureAuthentication_jdbc[]
*/

/*
//tag::configureAuthentication_jdbc_withQueries[]
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {
    
    auth
      .jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery(
            "select username, password, enabled from Users " +
            "where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            "select username, authority from UserAuthorities " +
            "where username=?");
    
  }
//end::configureAuthentication_jdbc_withQueries[]
*/

/*
//tag::configureAuthentication_jdbc_passwordEncoder[]
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {
    
    auth
      .jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery(
            "select username, password, enabled from Users " +
            "where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            "select username, authority from UserAuthorities " +
            "where username=?")
        .passwordEncoder(new StandardPasswordEncoder("53cr3t");
    
  }
//end::configureAuthentication_jdbc_passwordEncoder[]
*/
  
  
//
// LDAP Authentication example
//
/*
//tag::configureAuthentication_ldap[]
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {
    auth
      .ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
        .groupSearchFilter("member={0}");
  }
//end::configureAuthentication_ldap[]
*/
  
//tag::securityConfigOuterClass[]

}
//end::securityConfigOuterClass[]
```

Comment: You can use the @Qualifier annotation on your autowiring field with the bean name you want to inject as a value

Comment: Thanks, Martin. Yes, IntelliJ suggested using @Qualifier, so that makes sense. Unfortunately, I don't know what to put for the bean name. In learning about the @Qualifier annotation (.e.g., , I see that the bean name would come from an @Component annotation, but I searched for one in all of the program's files and can't find any instances of @Component. I searched for @Bean and found only one instance, but it has no name (not even any parentheses. Here is its code:
```

Comment: As explained in my prior comment, I can't find any "@Component" instances. Here is the only instance of "@Bean":

@ SpringBootApplication
public class TacoCloudApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TacoCloudApplication.class, args);
  }

  @ Bean
  public CommandLineRunner dataLoader(IngredientRepository repo) {
    return new CommandLineRunner() {
      @ Override
      public void run(String ...

Do you know how to identify the bean name that I'm supposed to put in my "@Qualifier" annotation? Or do you have another suggestion?

Comment: I have written a more complete answer below.

Comment: This isn’t a compilation error, and you’ll find hundreds of references if you google the error message.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I tried both:
//  @Qualifier("userRepositoryUserDetailsService")
  @Qualifier("inMemoryUserDetailsManager")

No more compilation error. When I run, they both generate this:

`Error starting ApplicationContext.
2020-10-30 12:41:57.867 ERROR 25512 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource ass]: etc.`

Additional advice? (Sorry, new to Spring, and google hasn't helped)

Comment: Above, Daniel said "I have written a more complete answer below." I saw that answer and responded to it. Now I don't see that answer, and I don't see any response to my question about the runtime error (now that the compilation error is gone). I have Google searched, and tried to contact the book's author, but no luck. Please help.